# Is it possible to publish Events to Facebook via the SDKs or API still?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Our work has a feature for Users which allowed them to publish (create) Events on Facebook using an older version of the API.

There was a large update to v2.0 in April (https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/04/28/april-30-migration/) and it seems it was around this time that Facebook no longer supported the publishing/deleting/updating of Events (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/event)

However I cannot find a concrete quote/patch note/set of documentation that firmly says Facebook no longer allows the Publishing of Events through any source (either the graph API or the SDKs).

Can anyone confirm/deny that publishing Events to Facebook is 100% no longer possible via the API/SDKs?

Comment: There is no way to create events using the API

Comment: Thank you.

Out of curiosity, do you know if it is possible (via API or the SDKs) to create a Page?

Or is the main functionality mostly Reading information, publishing posts/comments etc, and possibly updating pages?

Comment: You can not create pages either.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses!

Comment: @WizKid Is there a way to create an event for a Facebook Page via API or JavaScript SDK? Thanks.

Comment: I already answered that question